# How to align my div to the right side of container per element?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Hope your all well.

Is it possible to align my div to the right side within my container? I try using align functions but does not seem to work. is it possible?

Note, the alignment solution should be for div (chatline) and HTML code only, as i need another div to align (chatline) on the right or left etc. so please don't use CSS alignment on the hold container.

Any help would be grateful here. thanks Yummi

```css
body {
  background-color: #6B6B6B;
  margin: 50px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: darkgrey;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: .3;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}

#chattext {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}

.chatbox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  grid-template-columns: 500px;
  display: grid;
}

.bubble {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox">
  <div style="height:200px">
    <p class="bubble" id="chattext">This should be right > please use htnl code on this div to align</p>
    <p style="margin-top:70px;" class="bubble" id="chattext">stay left</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define new class and use it in every bubble you want it in right

```css
.right_chat {
    right:0;
}
```

another advice `id` prefer to use just for one element so in my code i change it to class and use it in html code

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;   
    font-family: Arial;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: .3;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}   
    .chattext {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}
.right_chat {
    right:0;
}
    .chatbox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    grid-template-columns: 500px;
    display: grid;
}
    .bubble {
    position: absolute;
    max-width:200px;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox">
<div style="height:200px"><p class="bubble chattext right_chat" id="">This should be right > please use htnl code on this div to align</p><p style="margin-top:70px;" class="bubble chattext">stay left</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

I didn't change the default behavior of the `bubble` class. Since the `bubble` is `position: absolute` I created one extra class named `right` that you can add on each `bubble` you want to be aligned on the right.

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;   
    font-family: Arial;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: .3;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}  

#chattext {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}
    
.chatbox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    grid-template-columns: 500px;
    display: grid;
}

.bubble {
    position: absolute;
    max-width:200px;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.message-wrapper .bubble.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox">
  <div class="message-wrapper" style="height:200px">
    <p class="bubble right" id="chattext">This should be right > please use htnl code on this div to align</p>
    <p style="margin-top:70px;" class="bubble" id="chattext">stay left</p>
  </div>
</div>
```